# Azure Devops: How to set permissions on work-items at the organization level?

Tags: permissions, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-devops-rest-api

What is the proper way to give user's of a certain Azure AD group access to create / delete / edit work items on Azure DevOps across all existing projects and any new projects that might be created without giving them any access to see the actual repos/code?

We make wide use of the Group Rules to allow a user of a given AzureAD group to have access to a given project.

However with those rules we seem to only be able to set the Access Level to:

- Basic
- Stakeholder
- Visual Studio Subscriber

In addition, we can select the following groups on the project with the Group Rules:

- Project Readers
- Project Contributors
- Project Administrators

However, all of these options seem to give at least read access to the Repos, which we do not want.

It looks like choosing the following groups, maps to the following Project Groups:

- Project Readers -> Readers
- Project Contributors -> Contributors
- Project Administrators -> Project Administrators

However, even in the permissions for the Project Groups I don't see any option which states "Repos", and we'd like to avoid manually changing the permissions for every Project Group to do what we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure AD is Microsoft’s cloud-based identity and access management service .We can use group rule to manage Access Level, projects and DevOps groups more easily,but we can't set permissions for work item and repo in it.

To set permissions on work items, we can only set them in the Security of Project Settings.
[image]

You can add your AAD group as a member to the azure devops group with permissions set up.
[image]

To set permissions on repo, you need to set it in Repos under Project Settings.
[image]

Comment: Lin - Is there anyway to set the default permissions on all projects or even on newly created projects?

Comment: If you want to set permissions on repo or workitem, there should be no way to set these on  organization level for all projects. The permissions that can be set for all projects are listed in the security of the organization settings,  the specific repo or work item permission settings can only be set separately in the projects.

Comment: That's unfortunate. There definitely should be a way to do this. In fact, a few Google searches show that I'm not the only person who wants to do this. In any case, thank-you for your help and response!

Comment: You are welcome :) You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions.